# Can't see Checkbox on asp.net form

Tags: c#, asp.net, validation, checkbox

I have this checkbox on my aspx:

```
<div class="curriculumLadoRegistrocompletediv>
    <asp:CheckBox ID="CheckBox1" runat="server" Text="Are you asp.net user group member?"  AutoPostBack="true"/>      
  </div>
```

However, i can see the `Text` but can't see the checkbox itself, can't figure out why, can somebody shed some light on this?

Thanks in advance!

Comment: please check your div class have any problem

Comment: Without seeing your CSS, I don't know for sure. But maybe you have a css style that is hiding the checkbox? Perhaps there is a `display: none` in your css? Use FireBug or Chrome to inspect the element.

Comment: Don't remember gonna check, thank you!

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Close the quote:

```
<div class="curriculumLadoRegistrocompletediv">
```

Comment: Thank you @afzalulh sorry i posted that div, actually it closes in the end of all textboxes, radiobuttons of my page, but thank you anyway

Comment: Not the div, it's the double quote for your class I have mentioned. Change `"curriculumLadoRegistrocompletediv` to `"curriculumLadoRegistrocompletediv"`.

Comment: @Kristian Koci: No problem!

Answer (score 1):

Possible solutions:

1. Try closing the class quote.
2. Look at your css file to see if the css hides any such elements like
   what @icemanind said
3. See if you have any default skin applied to check box that keeps the
   check box with `Visible="false"`

Comment: Thank you @Nisha it was actually the class quote :)